# jquery: hide input box if checkbox gets checked

Tags: jquery, html

i trying to hide input box for name if checkbox gets checked:

```
if($(#1step).checked){
     $("input[username="true").hide
}

<input username="true">
<input type="checkbox" id="1step"><label>step1</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

1) Wrap your value in quotes `' '` or double quotes `" "`

2) Use `$("input[username='true']")` instead of `$("input[username="true")`

3) Use `<label>` instead of `<lavel>`

4) Use **[change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event to keep track when your checkbox has been checked or unchecked

5) Trigger `change` event manually to make sure that the visibility of your textbox has been set properly on page load

Final code look like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#1step').change(function () {
        if ($('#1step').is(':checked')) {
            $("input[username='true']").hide();
        } else {
            $("input[username='true']").show();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ACN9/1/)**

or you can shorten your code to:

```
$(function () {
    $('#1step').change(function () {
        $("input[username='true']").toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ACN9/3/)**

Comment: thank you added my fade exampel with yours very much hepl thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to have change event handler listening to the change in the checked state of the checkbox and update the visibility of the textbox accordingly(you can use .toggle() to set it). Also you can manually fire the change() event after the handler is added so that the initial visibility of the text field will be set properly

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#1step').change(function () {
        $('input[username="true"]').toggle(this.checked)
    }).change();//initialize with correct display state
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wWTfa/)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$('#1step').change(function() {
    $("input[username='true']").toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

Make sure to trigger change event initially in case you have HTML coming with checked="true" by default.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z4LQG/